# Meu select não esta gerando resultado

Tags: sql, asp.net

Estou fazendo um select , este mesmo select testado no banco me retorna a informação que eu preciso , mais no meu codigo .net  da um erro falando que não esta gerando resultado o que sera que estou fazendo de errado

```
var NomeFuncionario = conexao.executeSelect("TB_FUNCIONARIO","NOME","ID_FUNCIONARIO="+teste1);
if (NomeFuncionario.Read())
    lblNome.Text = NomeFuncionario.GetSqlChars(0).ToString();
```

código da função:

```
public SqlDataReader executeSelect(String sTabela, String sCampos, String sWhereClause) 
{ 
    try {   
        string query = " SET DATEFORMAT dmy SELECT " + sCampos + " FROM " + sTabela;    
        if (!(sWhereClause.Equals("")))
            query = query + " WHERE " + sWhereClause;

        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, getConnection());

        return sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (ApplicationException e)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("App_Code/conexao/executeSelect", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: coloque o código da função `executeSelect` mas, ao que me parece, a sintaxe está completamente errada: `Select nome from tb_funcionario where id_funcionario = "+teste1+";";`

Comment: postei como resposta o codifo porque era muito extenso

Comment: adicionei o código na sua pergunta, exclua a resposta para manter a organização

Comment: e qual o valor de teste1 no momento da execução ?

Comment: Consegue nos mostrar o valor de: sCampos, sTabela e de sWhere?

Comment: scampos =id_funcionario , stablea = tb_funcionario , sWhere? = teste1 . que no momento da excução foi 25  e o certo era apresentar um nome de um funcionario